# Create invoice on specific sum programmatically in magento

Tags: magento

I know magento give possibility to create partial invoice. This is invoice on specific product from whole order. But I wonder is it possible to create invoice on specific sum, not product. 
For example I have an order with price 100$ that comprises two product 70$ and 30$. Can I create programmatically  invoice on 60$ ?